# Is there any implementation of Grassberger-Procaccia algorithm available?

Tags: .net, algorithm, math, implementation, time-series

I am looking for an implementation of [Grassberger-Procaccia algorithm](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grassberger-Procaccia_algorithm#Non-Stationary_Signals_and_Theiler_Correction) in .NET/C/C++, MATLAB or Java. I have been searching for it for a while, but it appears that the actual implementation has not been published anywhere and I don't really want to implement it myself as it will require much testing.

This algorithm allows to estimate correlation dimension of time series data. There is some MATLAB code [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27561-measures-of-analysis-of-time-series-toolkit-mats/content/MATS/CorrelationDimension.m), which does compute correlation dimension, but it seems to use some other algorithm for it.

My data is represented by {0,1,2} alphabet and is a non-linear signal with around 10^6 points per signal instance. I have around 100 sample signal instances which are grouped by some external characteristics. For these signals I need to calculate correlation dimensions and then apply some statistics to see if there is any differences between the groups. So the signal looks like this:

```
Signal1 = 0000000001000020010000001... 
Signal2 = 0000001200000200200202000...
Signal3 = 2222220000000220000100011...
```

Any link would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your input data a scalar time series or does each sample have a several dimensions?

Comment: @ellisbben I have updated my question, data has many hidden dimensions embeded in it?